# Supervisor Directory not propagated to Celery program

Tags: python, django, directory, celery, supervisord

I have a Django application (named pcycler) that I need running with Celery. I am attempting to deploy this in production with Supervisor.

I get an error when I run:

> supervisorctl start celery

Which gives me:

> celery: ERROR (abnormal termination)

Here is my celery.conf file, which is included in the supervisor.conf on start.

```
[program:celery]
command=/webapps/pcyclerenv/bin/celery -A pcycler worker -l info 

directory=/webapps/pcyclerenv/pcycler
user=pcycleruser
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile=/webapps/pcyclerenv/logs/celeryd_stdout.log
stderr_logfile=/webapps/pcyclerenv/logs/celeryd_stderr.log
redirect_stderr=false
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10
stopwaitsecs=600
killasgroup=true
priority=998
```

The contents of celeryd_stderr.log is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/webapps/pcyclerenv/bin/celery", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/webapps/pcyclerenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/__main__.py", line 30, in main
    main()
  File "/webapps/pcyclerenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 81, in main
    cmd.execute_from_commandline(argv)
  File "/webapps/pcyclerenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 769, in execute_from_commandline
    super(CeleryCommand, self).execute_from_commandline(argv)))
  File "/webapps/pcyclerenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 304, in execute_from_commandline
    argv = self.setup_app_from_commandline(argv)
  File "/webapps/pcyclerenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 464, in setup_app_from_commandline
    self.app = self.find_app(app)
  File "/webapps/pcyclerenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 484, in find_app
    return find_app(app, symbol_by_name=self.symbol_by_name)
  File "/webapps/pcyclerenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/utils.py", line 222, in find_app
    sym = symbol_by_name(app, imp=imp)
  File "/webapps/pcyclerenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 487, in symbol_by_name
    return symbol_by_name(name, imp=imp)
  File "/webapps/pcyclerenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/utils/__init__.py", line 92, in symbol_by_name
    module = imp(module_name, package=package, **kwargs)
  File "/webapps/pcyclerenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/utils/imports.py", line 101, in import_from_cwd
    return imp(module, package=package)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named pcycler
```

Naturally, I decided to go run this program for myself, to see if I can duplicate this error:

```
pcycleruser@raspberrypi:/webapps/pcyclerenv/pcycler$ pwd
/webapps/pcyclerenv/pcycler

pcycleruser@raspberrypi:/webapps/pcyclerenv/pcycler$ /webapps/pcyclerenv/bin/celery -A pcycler worker -l info

(... text and pickle deprecation warnings ...)

[2014-05-23 14:52:36,053: WARNING/MainProcess] /webapps/pcyclerenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/fixups/django.py:233: UserWarning: Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never use this setting in production environments!
  warnings.warn('Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never '

[2014-05-23 14:52:36,066: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@raspberrypi ready.
```

So that works. However, when I am in the wrong directory, such as the following:

```
pcycleruser@raspberrypi:/webapps/pcyclerenv/pcycler$ cd ..

pcycleruser@raspberrypi:/webapps/pcyclerenv$ pwd
/webapps/pcyclerenv

pcycleruser@raspberrypi:/webapps/pcyclerenv$ /webapps/pcyclerenv/bin/celery -A pcycler worker -l info

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/webapps/pcyclerenv/bin/celery", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/webapps/pcyclerenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/__main__.py", line 30, in main
    main()

(... exact same error as above ...)

ImportError: No module named pcycler
```

I get the exact same error as what is in the error logs! This leads me to assume that the directory isn't properly changed when I am running in supervisor.

**tldr**: Why isn't the directory in my supervisor.conf being applied when I run the command using supervisorctl?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the error, it was *really* dumb.

Supervisor conf files are order specific, so doing:

```
[program:celery]
directory=/webapps/pcyclerenv/pcycler
command=/webapps/pcyclerenv/bin/celery -A pcycler worker -l info 
(... the rest ..)
```

Solves the problem I'm having.